# Coq - Error when eliminating OR

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I don't know why, but in Coq, when trying to prove a program specification I get an error when trying to eliminate an OR hypothesis:

```
Error: Cannot find the elimination combinator or_rec, the elimination of the
inductive definition Logic.or on sort Set is probably not allowed.
```

This is the theorem I want to prove:

```
Definition nat_div_mod : forall a b:nat, not(b=0) -> {qr:nat*nat | P a b qr}.
```

This is the goal and context when the error happens:

```
a : nat
b : nat
H : b <> 0
IHa : {qr : nat * nat | P a b qr}
x : nat * nat
H2 : P a b x
H0 : snd x < b - 1 \/ snd x >= b - 1
______________________________________
{qr : nat * nat | P (S a) b qr}
```

Before this theorem, I have this definition and these imports:

```
Definition P (a b:nat) (qr:nat*nat) : Prop := ... (* specification of div/mod *)
Require Import Omega.
Require Import Mult.
```

I get the previous error when I try to use this tactic:

```
elim H0.
```

I don't really know what may be causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do case analysis on `H0` because `{qr : nat * nat | P (S a) b qr}` is a `Set` or `Type`. Only `or_ind` is defined for `or`, so it would need to be a `Prop` instead. If you use `sum` you'll have `sum_ind`, `sum_rec`, and `sum_rect`.

```
(snd x < b - 1) + (snd x >= b - 1)
```

`Prop` is designed that way so that it's consistent with certain axioms.